# Dictionary values change after class calling

Tags: python, dictionary, class, oop

I am new to Python and I tried to create a class which I want to use to update some dictionaries

From first file I get: {1: {'Files': {'FIRST_FILE': 'FirstPath1', 'SECOND_FILE': 'SecondPath1'}}}

But when I try to add the second file, the data from first file is taking the same values as the second file: {1: {'Files': {'FIRST_FILE': 'FirstPath2', 'SECOND_FILE': 'SecondPath2'}}, 2: {'Files': {'FIRST_FILE': 'FirstPath2', 'SECOND_FILE': 'SecondPath2'}}}

Why is it changing? I tried del

```
# This is a sample Python script.

# Press Shift+F10 to execute it or replace it with your code.
# Press Double Shift to search everywhere for classes, files, tool windows, actions, and settings.

info_template = \
    {
             'Files':
                    {
                    'FIRST_FILE': "N/A",
                    'SECOND_FILE': "N/A"
                    }

    }

class InfoGenerator:
    def __init__(self, _first_file_path, _second_file_path):
        self.first_file_path = _first_file_path
        self.second_file_path = _second_file_path


    def createInfoDict(self, Info) -> dict:
        """
        """

        Info['Files']['FIRST_FILE'] = self.first_file_path
        Info['Files']['SECOND_FILE'] = self.second_file_path

        return Info


# Press the green button in the gutter to run the script.
if __name__ == '__main__':
   files = {1: ["FirstPath1", "SecondPath1"], 2: ["FirstPath2", "SecondPath2"]}
   files_dict = dict()

   for file in files:
       Info_c = InfoGenerator(_first_file_path=files[file][0], _second_file_path=files[file][1])
       files_dict[file] = Info_c.createInfoDict(info_template)
       del Info_c
```

Comment: You keep using the same `info_template` instance. Each time the same one is updated with new data and never copied. You will need to make a `deep_copy` at some point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite the name, `info_template` is *not* being used as a "template".

`files_dict` does not contain two separate *copies* of `info_template` -- it contains two *references* to the **same** `info_template` object .

The second time `createInfoDict()` is called, it modifies the actual `info_template` object, which of course also modifies the first entry in `files_dict`, because it's **the same object**.

You can fix this by creating a new dict inside `createInfoDict()` and returning that, instead of modifying a dict that is passed in as an argument:

```
def createInfoDict(self) -> dict:

    return {
        'Files': {
            'FIRST_FILE': self.first_file_path,
            'SECOND_FILE': self.second_file_path
        }
    }
```